# Java: the same set of objects in two linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list, 2d

I would like to sort 2D nodes (points) in two dimensions (x and y) and also to allow fast addition and deletion. I would say that this can be done by two linked lists, but found, that Java's [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) hides linkage from user. I.e. if I found some node and delete it from one list, I am unable to delete it fast from another.

Is this solveable or I need to write my own class supporting two dimensions of linkage?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question. Why not creating a `Point` object?

Comment: I think one `LinkedList<Point>` is sufficient, right?

Comment: I need two: one sorting by X coordinate, another -- by Y

Comment: By fast, do you need `O(1)` addition and deletion or is `O(log n)` sufficient?

Comment: I would like O(log n) for addition and O(1) for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the same object from both lists create a wrapper class like so

```
class PointWrap{
    int id = 0;
    Point p = null;
    public PointWrap( int inid, Point inp){
        id = inid;
        p = inp;
    }
}
```

An insert would look like this

```
tree.put( new PointWrap( id++, point) );
```

When you iterate through to delete just save the id before the delete occurs. This way you can delete from the other list/tree as well.

Comment: see edit. The ID acts as a unique identifier that is incremented with each insert.

Comment: If delete, i need renumber consequenting items?

Comment: No, the id always increments.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a compound data structure.

Will you be reading or writing more? If reading more, use an ArrayList; if writing more, use a LinkedList. Have this structure store int[ ] and enter the values as {x, y} and have this structure sort, after each insertion block, by x value only.

Additionally, maintain an array that is populated with y values, not upon insert, but upon sorting of the x-list have this array populated with the values that are actually in the x-list.

Put all of this into a single class and tie the methods together under 1 hood & holy encapsulation batman!

You can have the class return int[2] from a getByX() or getByY()

A question to ask yourself first is, "Do I absolutely need both lists sorted all the time, or only during read operation blocks?" If your answer is the latter, this will work just fine for you.

Another thing to consider, will you need a queue, deque, stack, or all random access?